# Unescaped backslashes are Deprecated at mobility.prf:1

Tags: symbian

i am new to Qt for Symbian Development and i am stuck at one problem that when i tried to build my Qt Project then three Warnings are occurred there which stops the build process:

> WARNING:
>   D:\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\mkspecs\features\mobility.prf:1:
>   Unescaped backslashes are deprecated. WARNING:
>   c:\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\mkspecs\features\mobility.prf:1:
>   Unescaped backslashes are deprecated. WARNING:
>   c:\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\msvc2008\mkspecs\features\mobility.prf:1:
>   Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.

Please help me to rectify this issue that why these warnings are occurring. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it....
By just uninstalling the Qt and then re-install it...